# Derivative of trigonometric functions problem

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

Please help
Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$y=\cot3x\cos^2 4x$$

know how to derive the cot and cos but the only problem I have is what to do with $3x$ and $4x$. Please could someone help me with reasonable explanations.

Answer (score 2):

The $3x$ and $4x$ are *functions* of $x$.

To differentiate the cotangent of a function--or in general any function
of a a function--look to the Chain Rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x).$$

For example, in $\cot (3x),$ you apply the rule
using $\cot$ as $f$ and $3x$ as $g(x)$.
You get $g'(x)$ by differentiating $3x$, which is easy.
You can write $f'(g(x))$ by differentiating $\cot(3x)$ as if the
"$3x"$ were just a variable.

Speaking of treating an expression as if it were just a variable,
I tend to remember the Chain Rule better this way:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(u) = \left(\frac{d}{du}f(u)\right) \cdot \frac{du}{dx}.$$

To apply this to $\cot(3x)$ you can just set $u = 3x$.

The two copies of $du$ do not cancel each other out in the usual way
(at least in standard analysis), but they *look* like they do, and I 
find that to be a useful way to remember the rule.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP wanted. Most other answers are just solving it. So +1

Answer (score 0):

Here $y = \cot 3x\cdot \cos^2 4x$

Now Using Product Rule of Differentiation.

So $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\cot (3x)\cdot \cos^2 4x\right] = -\cot(3x)\cdot 2\cos 4x\cdot \sin 4x\cdot 4+\cos^2 4x\cdot -\csc^2(3x)\cdot 3$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, apply product rule as follows $$\frac{d}{dx}(y)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cot 3x\cos^2 4x\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cot 3x\frac{d}{dx}(\cos^2 4x)+\cos^2 4x\frac{d}{dx}(\cot 3x)$$
$$=\cot 3x(2\cos 4x(-\sin 4x))(4)+\cos^2 4x(-3\csc^2 3x)$$
$$=-4\cot 3x(2\sin 4x\cos 4x)-3\cos^2 4x\csc^2 3x)$$
$$=-4\sin 8x\cot 3x-3\cos^2 4x\csc^2 3x$$

Answer (score 0):

Derivation of trigonometric functions is 3 step. for example for $\cot^n()$

1) power step you have to wright $n\cot^{n-1}( )$

2) $\cot()\hookrightarrow‎‎ -(1+\cot^2( ))$

3)$( )'$

Now youse this and product rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following suggestive notation.

$$\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}\equiv \frac{\text{an infinitesimal small change in }  g}{\text{an infinitesimal small change in }  f}$$

As an example,
$$\frac{d\sin(x^2+1)}{d(x^2+1)} = \cos(x^2+1)$$
Of course one would never compute such a derivative by itself, but rater as a component of a larger calculation (when using the chain rule).

So let's apply this notation to your problem.
$$\begin{array}{lll}
y&=&\cot3x\cos^24x\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=&\displaystyle\frac{d(\cot3x\cos^24x)}{dx}\\
&=&\displaystyle\cot3x\cdot\frac{d\cos^24x}{dx}+\frac{\cot 3x}{dx}\cdot \cos^24x\\
[1]&=&\displaystyle\cot3x\cdot\frac{d\cos^24x}{d\cos4x}\cdot\frac{\cos4x}{d4x}\cdot\frac{d4x}{dx}+\frac{\cot 3x}{d3x}\cdot\frac{d3x}{dx}\cdot \cos^24x\\
\end{array}$$
I just wanted to point something out.
$\displaystyle\frac{d\cos^24x}{d\cos4x}$ may look odd, but all that it mean is
$$\frac{du^2}{du}\text{ where }u=\cos4x$$
so it evaluates to $\displaystyle\frac{d\cos^24x}{d\cos4x}=2\cos4x$

I think that should be enough for you to continue from [1]